# Can not set native resolution

Tags: 13.04, resolution

I almost month ago installed Ubuntu 13.04. It worked fine with 1366x768 resolution. But I changed it to 1280x1024 today and after that I can not set to 1368x768. Monitor shuts down. How can I set it back to original resolution?

Comment: Are the graphic drivers installed? I had the same issue before I installed them...

Comment: It is installed I think (I can't remember). But it worked fine without any problem. I switched the monitor with another one (with 19', native resolution 1366x768), works fine. If I connect back to my monitor it doesn't work. However i can see that 1366x768 is available.